# Django DetalView with simple method get

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a CBV DetailView and I would like to implement a search form in it. But when I do this, the usual query through this class does not work. Now I implement a search through a similar class. How to implement everything in one class. Below is a listing. (Google translator)

urls.py

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('transmitter/<int:pk>', TransmitterDetailView.as_view(), name='transmitter'),
    path('transmitter', TransmitterSearchDetailView.as_view(), name='search'),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TransmitterDetailView(DetailView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Transmitter
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        state_list = self.object.state().filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        context = super().get_context_data(object_list=state_list, **kwargs)
        return context


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TransmitterSearchDetailView(DetailView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Transmitter
    paginate_by = 5

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object =   Transmitter.objects.get(id_transmitter=request.GET.get('id'))
        state_list = self.object.state().filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        context = super().get_context_data(object=self.object, object_list=state_list, **kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        state_list = self.object.state().filter().order_by('-timestamp')
        context = super().get_context_data(object_list=state_list, **kwargs)
        return context
```

transmitter_list.html

```
<form id="searchbar" action="{% url 'main:search' %}" method="get">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Поиск">
 <hr>
 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search">Найти</button>
 <hr>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, nor what you are doing in that TransmitterSearchDetailView. Why have you duplicated that code in both get and get_context_data? Why in fact have you defined get at all?

Comment: Because if I implement everything in one class, then the usual query does not work for me, but it works only through the search form. In a common request on 'main: transmitter', the transmitter_id gives an error Transmitter matching query does not exist. Perhaps I do not correctly register the search function in the TransmitterDetailView, because I get the TransmitterSearchDetailView class as a result.